# Why do I get "F - -" on my Nikon camera?

Tags: nikon, dslr, troubleshooting, error

When I press the shutter release to focus, a message on the viewfinder displays `F--`.

Any photos snapped turn out black.

I switched the camera off, took out the battery and memory card and rested it a while, and then it was ok.

But again, after a few days, the error occurs again, and it seems it will keep happening.  What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Try detaching and re-attaching the lens.  The F-- error is related to an inability to control the lens aperture and may be due to a problem with the lens, the body or the connection to the lens.  Try removing and reattaching the lens, if that doesn't work, try another lens.  If that works, try the lens on another body if possible.  This should narrow down the source of the problem that needs to be addressed.